# Stackoverflow and function pointers

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, function-pointers

I'm quite lost on this one and I hope someone here could help.

My application consists of hundreds of functions evaluating numerical code (source is in the 5MB range each) and I manage the functions with a `std::map` to function pointers. 
What apparently happens is that I get a stack overflow when trying to pass an argument to one of the functions, accessed by a pointer to it:

gdb output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000001ec0df7 in xsectiond149 (sme=Cannot access memory at address 0x7fffff34b888
) at xsection149.c:2
2       Poly3 xsectiond149(std::tr1::unordered_map<int, Poly3> & sme, 
                           EvaluationNode::Ptr ti[], ProcessVars & s)
```

and xsection149.c:2 has only the opening brace for the definition of the function.

`/proc/<pid>/map` for the process shows for the address range closest to the address that triggers the error only this line:

```
7ffffff74000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 7ffffff73000 00:00 0                      [stack]
```

so the address in the above error is out of bounds.

Now my question: How do I resolve this problem? I can not wrap my head around as to what I could allocate on the heap...

The only think that happens in my main routine is:

```
// A map containing O(10^4) Poly3 (struct with 6 doubles)
tr1::unordered_map<int, Poly3> smetemp;
// populates smetemp
computeSMEs(smetemp);
// Map of function pointers of type, O(10^3) elements
tr1::unordered_map<int, xsdptr> diagfunctions = get_diagram_map();
```

How could this overflow the stack??

EDIT: I've tried to run it in valgrind, this is the error I get and google didn't give any meaningful info:

```
valgrind: m_debuginfo/storage.c:417 (vgModuleLocal_addDiCfSI): 
    Assertion 'cfsi.len < 5000000' failed.
==491==    at 0x38029D5C: ??? (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
```

**EDIT2**: Disassembling the function up to the point where it fails (0x0000000001ec0df7) gives me:

```
Dump of assembler code for function xsectiond149(std::tr1::unordered_map<int, Poly3,      std::tr1::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, Poly3> >,   false>&, std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<EvaluationNode>,    std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<EvaluationNode> > >&, ProcessVars&):
<...+0>:      push   %rbp                                                               
<...+1>:      mov    %rsp,%rbp                                                          
<...+4>:      push   %r15                                                               
<...+6>:      push   %r14                                                               
<...+8>:      push   %r13                                                               
<...+10>:     push   %r12                                                               
<...+12>:     push   %rbx                                                               
<...+13>:     sub    $0xc96b58,%rsp                                                     
<...+20>:     mov    %rdi,%rbx                                                          
<...+23>:     mov    %rsi,-0xc8b078(%rbp)      // this instr fails
```

and the first few lines of the function read:

```
Poly3 xsectiond149(std::tr1::unordered_map<int, Poly3> & sme,   
                   std::vector<EvaluationNode::Ptr> & ti, 
                   ProcessVars & s)
{
    Poly3 sum(0,0,0,-2);
    Poly3 prefactor, expr;

    // CF*CA^2*NF*NA^(-2)
    double col0 = 0.5625000000000000000000000000;

    prefactor = col0*ti[0]->value()*s.Qtpow2*s.epow2*s.gpow6;
    expr =       (128*(s.p1p2*sme[192]*s.mt - s.p1p2*sme[193]*s.mt +
       1/2.*s.p1p2*sme[195]*s.mt - 1/2.*s.p1p2*sme[196]*s.mt -
       s.p1p2*sme[201]*s.mt + s.p1p2*sme[202]*s.mt +
       1/2.*s.p1p2*sme[210]*s.mt - 1/2.*s.p1p2*sme[211]*s.mt -
       1/4.*s.p1p2*sme[216]*s.mt + 1/4.*s.p1p2*sme[217]*s.mt -
       s.p1p2*sme[219]*s.mt + s.p1p2*sme[220]*s.mt -
       1/8.*s.p1p2*sme[1209]*s.mt + 1/8.*s.p1p2*sme[1210]*s.mt +
       1/2.*s.p1p2*sme[1215]*s.mt - 1/2.*s.p1p2*sme[1216]*s.mt +
   // .....
}
```

(Note that I have changed the signature of the function during experimentation)

Can anyone make the ends meet to what is going on here? Which additional information would you need? Sorry, but I have almost no experience with asm.

**EDIT3**:
Increasing the stack size with `ulimit -s <size>` did the trick. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: A stack overflow or an access violation? Seems to be the latter, not the former.

Comment: I'd be curious to see the contents of the checkin that introduced this segv.

Comment: @GMan: I *think* it is a stack overflow, it's hard to tell. Actually accessing `smetemp` works fine before calling `xsectiond149(...)`, so I guess it is a problem in passing the argument to the function.

Comment: @bbtrb: You mean a stack overflow is causing an access violation? If you had a stack overflow, you'd get a stack overflow error (and wouldn't be able to continue running code, including code that has access violations). But you aren't, you're getting an access violation.

Comment: @sarnold: could be more specific as what you mean by "checkin" ?

Comment: @GMan: I guess ... I'm not very experienced with this type of errors.

Comment: looks like a simple stack overflow. Don't declare huge variables on your tiny thread stack =P

Comment: @bbtrb, if you've got 5megs of source code to work with, I assume it's all under source control. And you don't just wind up with 5 megs of source, it surely had to be working at some point in the past. So, what changed between when it was working and when it fails? Find _that_ checkin, and hopefully it'll be easier to spot the problem. :)

Comment: @sarnold: ahh, source control. Actually I'm dealing with 2.1GB of automatically generated source right now and this is the first phase of testing, so I expect things to fail :)

Comment: @tralamazza: yes yes, I know. But I have no idea what to do now ....

Comment: @bbtrb, my condolences, and best of luck! :D

Comment: Try disassembling that function in gdb. See what happens at 0x0000000001ec0df7 and where the bad pointer came from.

Comment: @LaC: Please see my second EDIT, id doesn't hep *me* much, but maybe you can see something wrong there...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the function `xsectiond149` needs a stack frame of about 13 MB (note the instruction `sub    $0xc96b58,%rsp`, and the failure as soon as it tries to write something down there two instructions later). You need to ensure that the thread has a large enough stack (by default it won't) before calling the function.

You might also look into changing your code generator to allocate more stuff on the heap instead of the stack.

Comment: Thank you! Your hint pointed me to `ulimit -s` on *nix, increasing stack size did the trick. Are there any limits, drawbacks of choosing the stack size too large?

Comment: In the memory space of your process, the stack grows downwards, while the heap grows upwards. Increasing the size of the stack reduces the space available for heap growth. You should also keep in mind that, if the increase applies to all threads, the effect will be multiplied. However, with a 64-bit address space, you don't have much to worry about, in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Get [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and run your program under Valgrind (using memcheck, the default tool) once built. This way you will have it much easier to locate the source of the fault.

You can also run Valgrind in a mode where it breaks into the debugger (usually GDB) and you can then use all the cool GDB commands to inspect values at stack frames of callers and so on.

Either way, if you are stuck, Valgrind should help you find some pointers where to continue.

As to your edit, here's my reply (quoting from the Valgrind source code, r11604 of storage.c):

```
445     /* sanity */
446     vg_assert(cfsi.len > 0);
447     /* If this fails, the implication is you have a single procedure
448     with more than 5 million bytes of code. Which is pretty
449     unlikely. Either that, or the debuginfo reader is somehow
450     broken. 5 million is of course arbitrary; but it's big enough
451     to be bigger than the size of any plausible piece of code that
452     would fall within a single procedure. */
453     vg_assert(cfsi.len < 5000000);
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. It didn't help however, please see the EDIT above.

Comment: See my update in the answer. I would strongly suggest that you inspect the preprocessed code and if that's half-way sane, dig into disassembly. Because apparently at least one function of your source has a humongous size or the debug reader is broken. Given the other strange symptom you see, I'd put my money on the first one.

Comment: Yeah, the functions have a huge size, but there is really nothing I can do about this... Please see my second EDIT for the disassembly until the point of failure.